# Am I a first time buyer if I own a share of my parents property?

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom, first-time-home-buyer

If my parents use the land registry to add me as a 10% owner of their house, would I still qualify as a first time buyer in reference to common first time buyer mortgage schemes?

Comment: country is needed for this kind of question

Comment: The reference to the "Land Registry" and the wording of the question makes me think this is a UK-based question, so I'm assuming that for now (and will edit the tag in). OP please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Note that if your parents have a mortgage, they would need to add you to that as well, and probably to their buildings insurance policy too. Out of interest, what's the reason for doing this?

Answer (score 9):

In the UK this would likely disqualify you from most "first time buyer" schemes.

For example, the [Ts & Cs for the Help To Buy ISA](https://www.helptobuy.gov.uk/documents/2015/12/scheme-rules.pdf) specifically define:

> “First Time Buyer” means an individual who:
>   (a) is not, and never has been, a Residential Property Owner; and [...]

and

> “Residential Property Owner” means an individual who owns an interest
>   in land,  whether in the United Kingdom or elsewhere [...]

However, ultimately you would need to check the specific definitions that an individual lender or service provider is using.